# objective-c multi protocols in one class correct syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax, delegates, protocols

I've a main class where I want to define two protocols (1 used by a class A, the other by class B) (ios 6.1, xcode 4.6.3 , ARK mode, storyboard project).

According to official syntax, all my code seems to be correct.
But when I try to use the second delegate , nothing work correctly, my 2nd delegate does not respond

```
**HEADER myProtocols.h** 
#import ...  
@class myProtocols;
@protocol myProtocol1 <NSObject>
// list of methods and properties
  doStuff:(float) myValue;
@end
@protocol myProtocol2 <NSObject>
// list of methods and properties
   doOtherStuff:(float) myValue2 andText:(NSString *)myText andType:(NSString *)myType;
@end
@interface  myProtocols:NSObject
{
   __unsafe_unretained id <myProtocol1> _myDelegate1;
    __unsafe_unretained id <myProtocol2> _myDelegate2;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <myProtocol1> myDelegate1;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <myProtocol2> myDelegate2;
@end

**MESSAGES myProtocols.m**
#import myProtocols.h
@implementation myProtocols
@synthesize myDelegate1 = _myDelegate1
@synthesize myDelegate2 = _myDelegate2
...
if ([_myDelegate1 respondsToSelector:@selector(doStuff:)])
   [_myDelegate1 doStuff:3.5];   **// THIS DELEGATE WORK VERY WELL**
...
if ([_myDelegate2 respondsToSelector:@selector(doOtherStuff:andText:andType:)])
   [_myDelegate2 doOtherStuff:4.5 andText:@"YES MAN" andType:@"YES BRO"];
                **// THIS DELEGATE DONT WORK, IT'S LIKE IT DOESNT INIT**
...
@end

**HEADER classA.h**
#import "myProtocols.h"
@interface classA: UIViewController <myProtocol1>
@property(strong, nonatomic) myProtocols *myProtoVC;
//-(void) doStuff:(float) myValue; according to comments, nothing to do :(
@end

**MESSAGES classA.m**
#import "classA.h"
@interface classA ()
@end
@implementation classA
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _myProtoVC = [[myProtocols alloc] init];
    _myProtoVC.myDelegate1 = self;
}
-(void) doStuff:(float) myValue
{
  NSLog(@" YES VALUE IS %f",myValue);
}

**HEADER classB.h**
#import "myProtocols.h"
@interface classB: UIViewController <myProtocol2>
@property(strong, nonatomic) myProtocols *myProtoVC;
//-(void) doOtherStuff:(float) myValue2 andText:(NSString *)myText andType:(NSString *)myType; according to comments, nothing to do :(
@end

**MESSAGES classB.m**
#import "classB.h"
@interface classB ()
@end
@implementation classB
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _myProtoVC = [[myProtocols alloc] init];
    _myProtoVC.myDelegate2 = self;
}
-(void) doOtherStuff:(float) myValue2 andText:(NSString *)myText andType:(NSString *)myType; 
{
  NSLog(@" YES VALUE IS %f and text %@ and type %@",myValue2,myText,myType);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to redeclare the protocols method on the interface of the class the are conform to the protocol `UIViewController <myProtocol2>` is enough, in this way the compiler make confusion, and probably see only the last one not the protocol declaration, because is the same method sign twice

Comment: So, if I've understand what you say, I must delete declaration of doOtherStuff method inside classB header, correct? 
I've do it, nothing change, always same situation. However thanks for you fast answers!

Comment: I've also comment declaration of doStuff method inside classA header, nothing change , MYDELEGATE1 work perfect, MYDELEGATE2 seems dead.

Comment: So finally I've find the problem. If I'm try to call myDelegate2 (for example : [_myDelegate2 doOtherStuff..] from a method inside myProtocols called only by the ClassA (myDelegate1) , myDelegate2 obviously result NIL. Mea culpa. It's solved.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I am writing now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my mistake is to call [_myDelegate2 doOtherStuff..] directly inside a function in myProtocols called only by classA. 
Then, if I want to call a function in myProtocols using both delegate I MUST init both these delegates in the class (A or B doesnt matter) I use to call this function:

```
**MESSAGES myProtocols.m**
#import myProtocols.h
@implementation myProtocols
@synthesize myDelegate1 = _myDelegate1
@synthesize myDelegate2 = _myDelegate2

-(void) pleaseDoIt 
{
if ([_myDelegate1 respondsToSelector:@selector(doStuff:)])
   [_myDelegate1 doStuff:3.5];   **// THIS DELEGATE WORK VERY WELL**
...
if ([_myDelegate2 respondsToSelector:@selector(doOtherStuff:andText:andType:)])
   [_myDelegate2 doOtherStuff:4.5 andText:@"YES MAN" andType:@"YES BRO"];
                **// THIS DELEGATE NOW WORK VERY WELL**
}
@end

**HEADER classA.h**
#import "myProtocols.h"
#import "classB.h"
@interface classA: UIViewController <myProtocol1>
@property(strong, nonatomic) myProtocols *myProtoVC;
@property(strong, nonatomic) classB *classBVC;

//-(void) doStuff:(float) myValue;
@end

**MESSAGES classA.m**
#import "classA.h"
@interface classA ()
@end
@implementation classA
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _myProtoVC = [[myProtocols alloc] init];
    _classBVC = [[myProtocols alloc] init];
    _myProtoVC.myDelegate1 = self;
    _myProtoVC.myDelegate2 = _classBVC   // THIS IS THE POINT!!!

    [_myProtoVC pleaseDoIt];
}
-(void) doStuff:(float) myValue
{
  NSLog(@" YES VALUE IS %f",myValue);
}
```